# Is it possible to make a class variable readonly from outside the class?

Tags: vb.net

I have a hierarchy kind of class, it would be very useful for me to set some of its values like child list as public so i can easily export a tree from the item but if the values were to be edited from outside the proper pathways everything would explode. Is it possible to make the variables accessible only from instances of its own class? or at least to have it read-only for anything outside the instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462673/vb-net-properties-public-get-private-set. Use `Get` and `Private Set`.

Comment: for it to be `accessible only from instances of its own class` they could also just use the backing field and then declare the property `ReadOnly Property FooBar`.

Comment: properties kind of negate the usefulness of lists though